# a question about decomposition of the cotangent space on a complex manifold M (from Griffiths and Harris)

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry

Recently, I am reading Griffiths and Harris' book 'principles of algebraic geometry '. In chapter 0, section ***DeRham and Dolbeault Cohomology***. they mention that By linear algebra, the decomposition
$$T^*_{\mathbb{C},z}(M)=T^{*'}_z(M)\bigoplus T^{*''}_z(M)$$
of the cotangent space of a complex manifold M at each point $p\in M$ gives a decomposition
$$\wedge^nT^*_{\mathbb{C},z}(M)=\bigoplus_{p+q=n} (\wedge^p T^{*'}_z(M)\bigotimes \wedge^q T^{*''}_z(M))$$
My question is what is $\bigotimes$ means here? Does it means tensor product? If so, why? In my mind, it should be  $\wedge$ here i.e we have
$$\wedge^nT^*_{\mathbb{C},z}(M)=\bigoplus_{p+q=n} (\wedge^p T^{*'}_z(M)\wedge\wedge^q T^{*''}_z(M))$$
For example, when n=2 (we assume $dim_{\mathbb{C}}M \ge 2$). The decomposition here should be
$$\wedge^2T^*_{\mathbb{C},z}(M)=\wedge^2 T^{*'}_z(M)\bigoplus \wedge^{1,1} T^{*'}_z(M)\bigoplus \wedge^2 T^{*''}_z(M))$$
where
$$\wedge^{1,1} T^{*'}_z(M)=T^{*'}_z(M)\wedge T^{*''}_z(M)=\{f(z)dz_i\wedge dz_{\bar{j}}\} $$
not
$$\wedge^{1,1} T^{*'}_z(M)=T^{*'}_z(M)\bigotimes T^{*''}_z(M)=\{f(z)dz_i\bigotimes dz_{\bar{j}}\} $$
I see many other book use the same symbol as Griffiths and Harris' book (for example 'Complex geometry; an introduction' by Daniel Huybrechts). Can anyone tell what's happening here. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

It's a question of identification.

Suppose $V$ is a (finite dimensional, say) vector space, and $V=U'\oplus U''$ is a decomposition of $V$ as a direct sum of subspaces. The natural map of $\oplus_{k+l =n}  \wedge^k U'\otimes \wedge^l U'' \rightarrow \wedge^n V$, given term-wise by
$$\alpha\otimes \beta \mapsto \alpha \wedge \beta,$$
is an isomorphism, where, on the right of the $\mapsto$, we are identifying  $\alpha$ and $\beta$ (a $U'$ form and $U''$ form respectively) with their images as $V$ forms.

[The map is clearly natural (does not depend on choice of bases, say). But one can use bases (choose a basis for $V$ taken from from bases of $U'$ and $U''$) to prove that the map is an isomorphism.]

The point of the tensor product on the left is that one is considering $U'$ and $U''$ as vector spaces each 'ignorant' of the other (i.e., the $\oplus$ of $U'\oplus U''$ is an external direct sum). The wedge product on the right makes sense for elements of a common [ambient] space. For instance, if $u_1$ and $u_2 \in V$, a popular definition/formula (away from characteristic 2) for $u_1\wedge u_2$ is
$$ u_1\wedge u_2 = 1/2( u_1\otimes u_2 - u_2 \otimes u_1 ).$$
That expression only makes sense because the $u_i$ belong to a common space: one cannot subtract an element of $U''\otimes U'$ from one of $U'\otimes U''$ without some kind of identification.

In your case, $U'$ is the $+i$-eigenspace of $J$, and $U''$ the $-i$-eigenspace of $J$, with $J$ an endomorphism on a vector space $V$ - so both $U'$ and $U''$ are subspaces.

You might like considering (dis?)similar semantics in the situation of an exact sequence of finite dimensional vector spaces
$$0\rightarrow U' \rightarrow V \rightarrow U'' \rightarrow 0.$$
Then there is a isomorphism (not dependent on choice of bases)
$$\wedge^{\rm top} U'\otimes \wedge^{\rm top}U'' \rightarrow \wedge^{\rm top} V,$$
where 'top' are the [top] dimensions of $U', U''$ and $V$ respectively.

And, of course, people 'abuse notation'. For instance,  one might well see things such as $[\alpha_1 \otimes X_1,\alpha_2\otimes X_2]$, or $[(\alpha_1 \otimes X_1)\wedge (\alpha_2\otimes X_2)]$, or ...., where $\alpha_i$ are 'forms,' and $X_i$ elements of a Lie algebra...

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I think I began to understand why is tensor product here when you said that 'U′ and U′′ as vector spaces each 'ignorant' of the other .... The wedge product on the right makes sense for elements of a common [ambient] space.'